# How "change" used in passive voice?

Tags: passive-voice

I read somewhere that the verb *change* isn't used in the passive voice in sentences like

> Times have changed.

That seems logical and natural to me, but what if I need to add information to the sentence about who is responsible for the change?

Would it be totally natural on GRE, TOEFL to use something like :

> Times were changed by X.

Comment: Tim changed the channel. The channel was changed by Tim.

Comment: Times have been changed by many factors. Not that I like that form.

Comment: _Times change_ is intransitive (no direct object). You can't do passive on intransitive clauses. Don't believe anything that you read somewhere.

Comment: Compare 'We drank the wine' (active) / 'The wine was drunk by us' (passive) / 'This wine drinks well' (neither active nor passive: the 'middle' usage. With 'Times have changed', for a completed process, the related 'ergative' usage).

Comment: _Times have changed_ is an expression meaning 'things are very different today from the way they were in [a particular period in the past]'. _Times have been changed by X_ is just not something anyone would say.